# Why are one-sided ideals used for the general notion of local rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, local-rings

Wikipedia on [local rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring) calls a *local ring* any ring with a unique maximal *left* or *right* ideal.

Up until now, I used to privately call these rings *left local* and *right local* respectively (realizing these notions are equivalent) and assumed that *local rings* were rings with a unique maximal *two-sided* ideal. This would include simple rings that aren’t skew fields as local rings – so for example matrix rings over skew fields.

> - Why does the correct generalization use one-sided ideals?
> - Wouldn’t it make sense to just speak of local modules in the general case?

Comment: I'm not familiar (anymore) with the subject, but I can think of two reasons that might apply to your first question:
1. It's due to historical reasons (not satisfactory).
2. It's easier to check either left or right ideals only, so when applying the definition you consider these and then the the one-sided definition applies more naturally.
Again: these are only thoughts, I am sure somebody more familiar with the branch can help you further

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case that the Jacobson radical is the intersection of all maximal two sided ideals. See for example

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50360/jacobson-radical-intersection-of-all-maximal-two-sided-ideals

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/775/what-is-an-example-of-a-ring-in-which-the-intersection-of-all-maximal-two-sided-i

So the condition that there is a unique maximal two sided ideal is not really generalizing the property that we want: that there is a unique simple module (up to isomorphism).

One could of course ask that the ring modulo the Jacobson radical is simple artinian, so a matrix ring over a skew field, but then one runs in to the problem that one cannot in general lift idempotents modulo the Jacobson radical (this we can do in semiperfect rings), so our ring will not necessarily be Morita equivalent to a local ring.

Comment: Thanks! Why do we want that there be a unique simple module up to isomorphism?

Comment: Because that's what's happening for commutative local rings.

Comment: Okay, so you say, we want to preserve as many properties of commutative local rings as possible? Having a uniquely associated simple ring (namely the the residue field in the commutative case) is not enough? It should be a residue skew field and/or we should have it be the unique simple module? Something like that?